# Do multiple BCC's count towards SMTP hourly email limits?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using the PHPMailer class for sending email updates to opt-in subscribers, and am occasionally hitting our host's hourly email limit.

Would grouping identical messages together and adding receiptiants as BCCs address this problem?

Obviously this would only be a short term solution until the list grows, but something is better than nothing for now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty hard to answer without knowing how your host is configured. But if it's done by a system administrator who knows his stuff, he would impose the limit on the number of emails actually delivered. Whether it's BCC, CC or 'TO', it's all the same. So it's unlikely that you will be able to bypass those limits by using BCC

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Looks like its time for a new solution all together!

Comment: It's not too difficult to set up your own SMTP server with qmail.